# Which is the best tool to test for Memory leak in Win32/COM application?

Tags: winapi, com, memory-leaks

I'm looking for a tool which can monitor a running application (Win32/COM) for a long duration (1-3 days) and detect memory leaks if any. Any suggestions?
It is a .NET Windows application calling lots of unmanaged code.

Comment: Are you looking to detect memory leaks in the unmamanged code or are you looking to detect memory leaks in the .Net application (leaking unmanaged resources - not properly disposing, etc)?

Comment: I'm looking for both, but mostly in unmanaged code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Memory Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp/memory/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

iJeeves, the combination of BoundsChecker and .NET memory profiling should help you with your memory analysis. DevPartner Studio 10.5 ships February 4, 2011 with 64-bit application support. Depending on your application raw memory footprint, you may run x86 build configurations with the error dectection memory tracking analysis as long as you keep below the 2gb overall process virtual address limit, 3gb if you link the exe with LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE and run on an x64 OS with extra RAM. The x64 build configuration will let you go up as high as your system RAM allows, at least until you start paging and performance grinds to a standstill. You can run BC error dection for your native code under the .NET process, but object leaks or held references in managed code require a second pass using the .NET memory profiler. We do not yet have a single pass analysis that can handle the mixed C++ and .NET code with full mixed stack traces but we can handle managed code above the line, any PInvokes that cross the line, and all native activity below the line in two passes. Shameless plug: I work on the DevPartner team. The links above pointing to microfocus.com acurately resolve to DevPartner pages. Look for DPS 10.5 when it ships and pull down the eval to see if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

[AQTime](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/) is nice, I used it several times and it helped me with some tricky bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use [Bounds Checker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BoundsChecker) but nowadays I either use the Micrsoft inbuilt [CRT library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf(VS.71).aspx) or build my own.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a pay$'s tool then [DevPartner](http://www.microfocus.com/products/DevPartner/StudioProfessionalEditionCapabilities.asp) is well worth using. It has memory leak detection for managed, and unmanaged code.

Answer (score 0):

[Application Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948(VS.80).aspx) is free and from Microsoft. It detects memory leaks, double frees, overwrites and many other things. I use it all the time and it has helped me track down some nasty issues.